# how to show promp box with configurable buttons

Tags: extjs

can you please help me out.

I need to show a promp box to user with 3 buttons i.e. previous,next and close.

basically this is for searching a node in the tree panel , user will enter a string and it will search for the node.

on clicking of a next button the application should find the next child with given string.

here i am not able to show the prompt box with more then 2 buttons.

i am using following code.

```
Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Find','Please enter the search string',function(btn,text)
{
    if(btn == 'ok')
    {
        var treePanelRootNode = Ext.getCmp('dimTree').getRootNode();
        var searchResult = treePanelRootNode.findChild('atrribute',text,true);
    }
}
```

1) how to show more than 2 buttons ?

2) how to configure the button text ?

3) how to prevent the msgbox from hiding once user clicks on ok button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On more exploring the sencha docs for extjs, I found answer for the first 2 questions.

following is my code :

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
title: 'Find',
msg: 'Please enter the search string',
buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNOCANCEL,
buttonText:{yes:"Next",no:"Previous",cancel:"Close"},
prompt: true,
fn: function(){},
});
```